# Multiple concurrent webservice requests in ASP.NET using threads

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, web-services

I need to make multiple requests to a webservice at the same time. I thought of creating a thread for each request. Can this be done in ASP.NET v3.5?

Example:

```
for(int i = 0; i<=10; i++)
{
   "Do each Request in a separate thread..."
}
```

Comment: -1 Your question does not indicate any research effort.

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific? If this is related to sending data from server to db, you could fire multiple web services

Comment: Probably the best question to ask is, "do I really need to make this multithreaded?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following pattern can be used to spin off multiple requests as work items in the `ThreadPool`. It will also wait for all of those works items to complete before proceeding.

```
int pending = requests.Count;
var finished = new ManualResetEvent(false);
foreach (Request request in requests)
{
  Request capture = request; // Required to close over the loop variable correctly.
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
    (state) =>
    {
      try
      {
        ProcessRequest(capture);
      }
      finally
      {
         if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref pending) == 0) 
         {
           finished.Set();  // Signal completion of all work items.
         }
      }
    }, null);
}
finished.WaitOne(); // Wait for all work items to complete.
```

You could also download the [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609) backport for 3.5 and then use `Parallel.For` to do the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

While the oportunities to what you can use vary depending of what and where you would like to use paralelism in your code. I would suggest that you start off by using the new [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) class from .NET 4.0.
Example would be:

```
Task backgroundProcess = new Task(() =>
                {
                    service.CallMethod();
                });
```

This will get you started. After that I suggest that you do some reading because this is a very broad subject. Try this link:

http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: I'm using .Net 3.5, I think is not possible to use this Class!

Comment: @tomcamara - read the article I posted in my answer.If you use .NET 3.5 then you can use thread pool or just instantiate a new thread. Again it all depends on the usage.

Answer (score 0):

If the webservice calls are asynchronous I don't see how have multiple threads will accomplish anything.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 3.5 you can use ThreadPool QueueUserWorkItem method. Plenty of examples on the web.